# Subfield of degree $p$ of $\mathbf{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^2})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, gauss-sums

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3196764/221219), Keith Conrad claims that a generator of the subfield of degree $p$ over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ of $\mathbf{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^2})$ is given by $$\sum_{a^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod{p^2}} \zeta_{p^2}^a.$$

I don't see why this is true.

In any case, it is not true that the subfield of degree $p-1$, which is obviously $\zeta_{p}$, is generated by $\sum_{a^{p}\equiv 1\bmod{p^2}} \zeta_{p^2}^a$, which comes out to be $0$ .

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: That element is certainly fixed by the order $(p-1)$-subgroup of the Galois group. All one needs then is to show it's not in the ground field.

Comment: Yes, I understand that: if we write $H=\{ a\in (\mathbf{Z}/p^2\mathbf{Z})^\times \mid a^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod{p^2}\}$, then this element is in the fixed field $\mathbf{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^2})^H$, which has degree $p$ over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ (= index of $H$ in the Galois group).

Comment: What I would do if I had this question would be to write down those sums explicitly for easy cases ($p=3,5,...$) to see a pattern and get a feeling for those sums. Have you tried that? Actually, Keith Conrad looks at the case $p=3$ in his linked answer. -- As for "the other Gauß sum", you already say it is $0$, that's certainly in the ground field.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg that's what I did. We have for $p=3$: $\zeta_{3^2}+\zeta_{3^2}^{-1}$ and for $p=5$: $\zeta_{5^2}+\zeta_{5^2}^7+\zeta_{5^2}^{-1}+\zeta_{5^2}^{-7}$. The only pattern I see is that if $x\in H$, then $-x\in H$.. I am very curious to see a proof Keith Conrad might have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $\zeta = \zeta_{p^2}$, $K=\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta)$. Note that for $p\nmid a$, $\text{Tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p}(\zeta^a)=0$, this follows from the appearance of cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{p^2}$.

Let $$x = \sum_{a^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod{p^2}} \zeta^a$$
we already know $x$ is in the degree-$p$ subfield of $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta)$. Assume $x\in \mathbb{Q}_p$, then taking trace both sides, gives $\text{Tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p}(x)=p(p-1)x=0$, so $x=0$. Therefore
$$p-1 = \sum_{a^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod{p^2}} (1-\zeta^a)$$
each $v_p(1-\zeta^a) > 0$, but $v_p(p-1) = 0$, contradiction. Hence $x\notin \mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: Last question, shouldn't we calculate the valuation $v_{\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_{p^2})}(-)$ ? Because the elements $1-\zeta^a$ are not in $\mathbf{Q}_p$...

Comment: $v_p$ extends uniquely to any algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, so $v_p(1-\zeta^a)$ makes sense after the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: To show something is in the ground field, you have to check if it is fixed by *every* element of the Galois group.

Added: Here's an argument similar but a slightly different from the other answer. Call $$x:= \sum_{a^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod{p^2}} \zeta_{p^2}^a.$$ Via $(\mathbb Z/p^2)^\times \simeq Gal(\mathbb Q_p(\zeta_{p^2}) \vert \mathbb Q_p)$, $b \mapsto \sigma_b:=[\zeta_{p^2} \mapsto \zeta_{p^2}^a]$ we have

$$\sigma_b(x) = \sum_{a^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod{p^2}} \zeta_{p^2}^{ba}.$$

Now since $(\mathbb Z/p^2)^\times = \langle 1+p \rangle \times \{a \in (\mathbb Z/p^2)^\times: a^{p-1}=1\}$ (the first being the subgroup of order $p$, the second the one of order $p-1$), we get
$$\sum_{l=1}^p \sigma_{1+p}^l(x) = \sum_{a \in (\mathbb Z/p^2)^\times} \zeta_{p^2}^{a}$$
which is
$$=Tr_{\mathbb Q_p(\zeta_{p^2})\vert \mathbb Q_p}(\zeta_{p^2})=0.$$

This contradicts $\sigma_{p+1}(x)\stackrel{?}=x$ unless $x =0$ (which is the case for "the other Gauß sum", where a completely analogous argument goes through until here.)

So we need to show $x \neq 0$. The other answer does that with $p$-adic valuation; surely there's other ways.

Comment: @Heniz Doofenschmirtz   How do you know $\sigma S \neq S$?

Comment: HeinzDoofenschmirtz: It goes somewhat like this, but as @pisco points out, there is a subtlety to show that inequality (whereas for "the other sum", there is equality which is maybe not obvious on first sight.)

Comment: We can use that $1+p$ has order $p$ hence $(1+p)^{p-1}\not\equiv 1\bmod{p^2}$ so $\sum_a \zeta^a\neq \sum_a \zeta^{a(1+p)}$. I am going to accept your answer since it is the simplest one :D

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I just realised that argument is not correct.. Do you have an alternative argument to show these sums are not equal?

Comment: Heinz: See edit. I admit @pisco's answer looks more elegant now.

Comment: How does $\sum_{\ell=1}^p \zeta_{1+p}^\ell(x)=0 \implies x=0$ ?

Comment: Assuming $ \sigma_{1+p}(x)=x$, we get $ \sigma_{1+p}^l(x)$ for all $l$ and hence $\sum_{l=1}^p \sigma_{1+p}^l(x)=px$ which is $=0$ only if $x=0$.